# How do I apply the fact that every nonempty subset of a well-ordered set has the smallest element in this proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I have to prove this: Show that in a well-ordered set, every element except the largest(if one exists) has an immediate successor.

Here is what I have:
Let **A** be a well-ordered set.

let **a** belong to the set **A**.

Consider the set **S** = {**b** belongs to set **A** |**a** < **b**}

We want to use the fact that every nonempty subset of a well-ordered set has the smallest element.

If **a** is not the largest element of the set, then **(a,b) = {x | a < x < b)** = nonempty set,
and has the smallest element **b**. Then **b** is the immediate successor of **a** if **a<b** and if there is no **x** such that **a < x < b**.

Therefore, in a well-ordered set, every element except the largest (if one exists) has an immediate successor.

I am correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, that does not work: you pulled $b$ out of thin air. At the very least you need to say that if $a$ is not the largest element of $A$, then there is some $b\in A$ such that $a<b$; **then** you can consider the interval $(a,b)$. However, that interval may be empty, in which case it does not have a smallest element. And even if it is non-empty and therefore does have one, you cannot call that element $b$: you’ve already used that name for something else.

But in fact there’s no reason to look at such an interval in the first place. The point is that if $a$ is not the largest element of $A$, then $S\ne\varnothing$, and therefore $S$ has a least element $s$. Now show that $s$ is an immediate successor of $a$ by showing that there is no $b$ such that $a<b<s$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a$ is not the largest element. This means by definition that $U_a:=\{x: x > a\}$ is non-empty. As $X$ is a well order $\min(U_a)$ exists.

As $\min(U_a) \in U_a$ we know $a < \min(U_a)$. If there would exist some $b \in (a, U_a)$, then $b > a$ so $b \in U_a$ but at the same time $b < \min(U_a)$ contradicting the minimality of $\min(U_a)$. So no such $b$ can exist and so $(a, \min(U_a))$ is empty.

This is by definition what it means for $\min(U_a)$ to be the immediate successor of $a$, often denoted by $a^+$ in order theory.